# How to add checkbox to the table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, html-table

I have creating a html table with javascript function in a page. and i need to create a checkbox in each of the last column in each row from my table. I also want the value of checkbox should be same as that of element in a(for further use).  i don't know how to do that. anyone can help me? please give me an example for that.

the code used by me is this:-

```
//script.js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];

  var b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];

  var c = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];

  html = "<table><tr>";

  for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    j = i+1;
    html += "<td>" + j + "</td>" + "<td>" + a[i] + "</td>" + "<td>" + b[i] + "</td>" + "<td>" + c[i] + "</td>";
    html += "<td value="a[i]"> <input type="checkbox"> </td>";
    html += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  html += "</tr></table>";
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
});
```

HTML code is:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
        <head>
                <title>A</title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

                <!-- jQUERY UI CSS -->
                <link href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container"></div>
            <!-- Load the CDN first -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous" >
            </script>

            <!-- If CDN fails to load, serve up the local version -->
            <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js" ><\/script>');
            </script>

            <!-- jQUERY UI -->
            <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>

            <script src="script.js" ></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"<td value="a[i]"> <input type="checkbox"> </td>"` is plain wrong.

Comment: So many things wrong with your syntax... https://jsfiddle.net/12b5savk/

Comment: So many strange loading of jQuery too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try template literals - you have quote issues and var issue in this line

`html += "<td value="a[i]"> <input type="checkbox"> </td>";`

Also you have too few `<tr> and too many` `

```js
const a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
const b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];
const c = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];
let html = [];
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  html.push("<table><tbody>");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    html.push(`<tr><td>${j}</td><td>${a[i]}</td><td>${b[i]}</td><td>${c[i]}</td>`);
    html.push(`<td value="${a[i]}"><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>`)
  }
  html.push("</tbody></table>");
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html.join("");
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: can you please help me in answering this question and thanks for this answer:-[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63479963/how-to-use-checked-values-in-table-to-make-another-table-using-javascript) @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double-quotes with a `\` like `\"`.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];

  var b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];

  var c = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];

  html = "<table><tr>";

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    html += "<td>" + j + "</td>" + "<td>" + a[i] + "</td>" + "<td>" + b[i] + "</td>" + "<td>" + c[i] + "</td>";
    html += "<td value=\"" + a[i] + "\"> <input type=\"checkbox\"> </td>";
    html += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  html += "</tr></table>";
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```