# How to use checked values in table to make another table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I have creating a html table with javascript function in a page. and i need to create a checkbox in each of the last column in each row from my table1 and if the checkbox is checked then the elements of table1 is to be added to table2 without checkbox. I don't know how to do that. anyone can help me? please give me an example for that.

the code used by me is this:-

```js
const a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
const b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];
const c = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];
let html = [];
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  html.push("<table><tbody>");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    html.push(`<tr><td>${j}</td><td>${a[i]}</td><td>${b[i]}</td><td>${c[i]}</td>`);
    html.push(`<td><input type="checkbox"  value="${i}" name="code"></td></tr>`)
  }
  html.push("</tbody></table>");
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html.join("");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var y = 0;
  $("input[type='checkbox']").onclick(function() {
    var code1 = $("input[name='code']:checked").val();
    for (var x = 0; x < code1.length; x++) {
      if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          html1.push("<table><tr>");
          y = y + 1;
          html1.push(`<tr><th>${y}</th><td>${a[x]}</td><td>${b[x]}</td><td>${c[x]}</td></tr>`);
          html.push("</table>");
        });
      });
  });
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html1.join("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: table should be created on clicked of checkboxes ? or for all checkboxes ? Also ,  you have some typo in your code `name.length` should be `code1.length` .Here `html.push("</table>");` should be `html1.push..` and many more please correct that and update your question .

Comment: I made you a [mcve] snippet. It gives errors

Comment: can i send you google drive link as there are lot of files @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

This is likelier closer to what you wanted

I do suggest you do not just throw some guessed code together - the code you posted was a mess of event handlers, DOM handling and jQuery

```js
const a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
const b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];
const c = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];
let html = [];
let html1 = [];
$(function() {
  html.push("<table><tbody>");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    html.push(`<tr><td>${j}</td><td>${a[i]}</td><td>${b[i]}</td><td>${c[i]}</td>`);
    html.push(`<td><input type="checkbox" value="${i}" name="code"></td></tr>`)
  }
  html.push("</tbody></table>");
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html.join("");

  $("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      let y = 0;
      const code1 = this.value
      for (var i = 0; i < code1; i++) {
        html1.push("<table><tbody>");
        y = y + 1;
        html1.push(`<tr><th>${y}</th><td>${a[i]}</td><td>${b[i]}</td><td>${c[i]}</td></tr>`);
        html1.push("</tbody></table>");
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html1.join("");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
const b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];
const c = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];
let html = [];
let html1 = [];
$(function() {
  html.push("<table><tbody>");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    html.push(`<tr><td>${j}</td><td>${a[i]}</td><td>${b[i]}</td><td>${c[i]}</td>`);
    html.push(`<td><input type="checkbox" value="${i}" name="code"></td></tr>`)
  }
  html.push("</tbody></table>");
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html.join("");
  var y = 0;
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function() {
    if (this.checked == true) {
      const i = this.value
        html1.push("<table><tbody>");
        y = y + 1;
        html1.push(`<tr><th>${y}</th><td>${a[i]}</td><td>${b[i]}</td><td>${c[i]}</td></tr>`);
        html1.push("</tbody></table>");
    }

    if (this.checked == false) {
      const i = this.value
        html1.pop("<table><tbody>");
        y = y - 1;
        html1.pop(`<tr><th>${y}</th><td>${a[i]}</td><td>${b[i]}</td><td>${c[i]}</td></tr>`);
        html1.pop("</tbody></table>");
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html1.join("");
  });

});`enter code here`
```